# "Property set method not found" error during reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to reflect over some class properties and set them programmatically, but it looks like one of my PropertyInfo filters isn't working:

```
//Get all public or private non-static properties declared in this class (no inherited properties) - that have a getter and setter.
PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty );
```

I'm getting an error on the line

```
pi.SetValue(this, valueFromData, null);
```

Because the property has only a `get{}` method, no `set{}` method.

My question is, why wasn't this property filtered out of props? I thought that was the purpose of BindingFlags.SetProperty.

The property not getting filtered out is:

```
    public String CollTypeDescription
    {
        get { return _CollTypeDescription; }
    }
```

Note that I want to filter properties that won't work ahead of time because I'm listing them all at once. I **don't want to use** `pi.GetSetMethod()` after the fact to determine whether I can use the setter.

Comment: @dtryon - no - he's OR-ing together the flags for the options he wants to set.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From the documentation:

> BindingFlags.SetProperty
>
> Specifies that the value of the specified property should be set. For
> COM properties, specifying this binding flag is equivalent to
> specifying PutDispProperty and PutRefDispProperty.

`BindingFlags.SetProperty` and `BindingFlags.GetProperty` **do not** filter properties that are missing setters or getters, respectively.

To check if a property can be set, use the `CanWrite` property.

```
if (pi.CanWrite)
    pi.SetValue(this, valueFromData, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - can't use CanWrite because this only reveals public setters, and I can still make use of private setters since I'm doing this from within the class.

Comment: @Alain -- Are you sure? I just did a test with a private property with a getter and setter. The CanWrite property returned true for that private property.

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part. You're correct - the two are interchangeable, and since your method doesn't require a null test, it's preferable.

Comment: There is a peculiarity I discovered with a Silverlight property, [ButtonBase.IsFocused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.isfocused(v=vs.95).aspx), where its assembly internal setter will return true for `CanWrite`. It may be preferable to use `pi.GetSetMethod != null` if you need to avoid this consideration.

Comment: fwiw, I ran into the opposite with a property that only had a setter (it's a long story). So I used `pi.CanRead` too to make sure I only get properties that also have a getter.

Comment: In my case missing SET property in variable.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to ken for the information. It looks like the best solution I can get it to filter them out by testing GetSetMethod(true) in a LINQ filter:

```
// Get all public or private non-static properties declared in this class
// (e.g. excluding inherited properties) that have a getter and setter.
PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance |
                   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(p => p.GetGetMethod(true) != null && p.GetSetMethod(true) != null)
    .ToArray();
```

Alternatively, using `CanRead` and `CanWrite`:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance |
                   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
    .ToArray();
```

It's unclear to me whether these different approaches will yield different results for different protection levels of the get/set methods.

Comment: See my comment on my answer. CanWrite is returning 'true' for me for private properties. Is it not working the same way for you?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
    public class CustomBinder
{
    public static void BindModel(object myClass)
    {
        var stringItems = myClass?.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();

        if (!(stringItems?.Count > 0)) return;

        foreach (var propertyInfo in stringItems)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.GetValue(myClass, null) != null)
            {
                var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(myClass).ToString().Replace(...);
           if(propertyInfo.CanWrite)
                propertyInfo.SetValue(myClass, val);
            }

        }

    }
    public static void BindModel(List<string> listString)
    {
        if (!(listString?.Count > 0 )) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < listString.Count; i++)
            listString[i] = listString[i].Replace(...);

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand the GetProperties() method so that it returns every property that has `BindingFlags.GetProperty` **or** `BindingFlags.SetProperty`.
So if you want only properties that have setters you must remove the `BindingFlags.GetProperty` flag. But I did not tested it so I can be wrong.

My answer got a -1. So it seems that my answer is wrong.