# SSIS Script component can not find Property property set methid

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a task where i am reading from flatfile  and i want to replace the values where to space where i find tab. when i run the below script it is giving me error at runtime stating that  Property set method not found.   below screen shot shows the script and runtime error.  any help is welcome 
[image: Error screen at runtime]

this is my script code

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo dataColumn in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (dataColumn.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("_isnull") == false && dataColumn.PropertyType == typeof(string))
{
        object objValue = dataColumn.GetValue(Row, null);
        if (objValue != null)
        {
            string value = objValue.ToString();
            value.Replace("\t", " ");
            dataColumn.SetValue(Row, value, null);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that not all properties on `Input0Buffer` have a setter. Can you confirm this ? Check similar SO posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431869/c-sharp-reflection-setvalue-can-not-find-set-accessor) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364092/property-set-method-not-found-error-during-reflection)

Comment: got that part to work. I had the input0 to read only. Thanks..