# Unity Player throws excpetion: System.ArgumentException: Get Method not found for 'hideFlags'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

So i have a ComponenetCopier script that, what a suprise copies scripts.

The problem is that it does not work when i build my game, it jsut drops the following error and aborts the process, with the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Get Method not found for 'hideFlags' at System.Reflection.MonoProperty

The code where it dies is here:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
Debug.Log("Do i die here?");
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
     property.SetValue(myNew_Component, property.GetValue(original, null), null);
}
```

I have no idea why it fails, when it works in editor mode, but this kinda bugs me for days now.
Help is greatly appreciated...

Ps: I'm copying my components using reflection.

Comment: I Instantiate a GameObject, then when that GamObject is no longer needed i copy some of its components to a new Object.

Comment: Hm this sounds like there should be better designs for what you are trying to achieve ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think hideFlags is refering to this => `UnityEngine.HideFlags` [Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideFlags.html)

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        // Add this or else u might run into problems later
        if (!property.CanWrite)
        {
            continue;
        }
        // Hide flags is an Enumeration. the default value for it is HideFlags.None 
        // i assume u dont chnage this value, so for your use case this will be Ok
        if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum && property.ToString() == "UnityEngine.HideFlags hideFlags")
        {
            property.SetValue(my_Component, HideFlags.None);
            continue;
        }
        property.SetValue(my_Component, property.GetValue(original));
    }
```

The above code should do the trick

Comment: @Willer .. isn't that basically what I proposed as well ...?

Comment: @derHugo Yours looks better tbh, and i dont see why it would not work, unless a new error appeared

Answer (score 3):

See [`Object.hideFlags`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-hideFlags.html)

> Should the object be hidden, saved with the Scene or modifiable by the user?

and [`HideFlags`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideFlags.html)

> Bit mask that controls object destruction, saving and visibility in inspectors.

Since in a build there are no scenes or inspectors to be modified, saved and hidden this property seems to make sense only in the Editor.

So you should add a check using [`CanRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canread) and [`CanWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite) like

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
Debug.Log("Do i die here?");
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if(!property.CanRead || !property.CanWrite) continue;

    property.SetValue(myNew_Component, property.GetValue(original, null), null);
}
```

---

Additionally you could try to use the overload of [`GetProperties(BindingFlags)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties#System_Type_GetProperties_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) and pass in the according [`BindingFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags)

if nothing is passed in it is

> equal to `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public`

---

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9364092/7111561) are some further examples. In particular also using the checks [`GetGetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getgetmethod) and [`GetsetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod) like e.g.

```
if(property.GetGetMethod(true) == null || property.GetSetMethod(true) == null) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks, i will check this!